# How to make horizontal scrollbar on rightside div?

Tags: html, css

#### Here codepen **[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/xOKpQa)**

`fixedTable-body` div contain more `ul` blocks. so i need  **horizontal scrollbar**  on rightside `fixedTable-body` div.

the left side table **Row -1 .. Row -10** is fixed.

**Left Side**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row - 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 8</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Row - 9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row - 10</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Rightside**

```
<div class="fixedTable-body">
    <ul class="list-unstyled product-detail-list">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
      <li>J</li>
    </ul>    
    </div>
```

Comment: set height for 'fixedTable-body' & overflow:auto

Comment: @Sinto :  now i update my question.. Check it.. i need horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Sorry i will update

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to give a fixed height and an overflow-y.

```
.fixedTable-body {
    height: 300px; /*for example*/
    overflow-y: scroll;    
}
```

For a horizontal scrollbar, just use width and x instead:

```
.fixedTable-body {
    width: 300px; /*for example*/
    overflow-x: scroll;    
}
```

Comment: i've updated my answer to handle horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 100px;
</style>
<div class="fixedTable-body">
    <ul class="list-unstyled product-detail-list">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
      <li>J</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Check & set a width, so that you can see the scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixedTable-body {
     /*for example*/
  width:100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;    
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.fixedTable-body ul li {
display:inline-block;
 }
```

Above css will work for horizontal scrollbar.